# Autodesk forge (plateform service) in our application in a "on premise" way

Tags: autodesk, forge, on-premises-instances

we are looking for a way to use Autodesk forge API in our application in a "on premise" way.
We have already built a solution using Forge API viewer that relies on US/EMEA servers.
And a couple of years ago, an Autodesk developer told me that it was not possible to set an on premise solution.
But actually we have several new and old customers, that store very sensitive data that cannot be stored else where that their own network and servers.
Can someone give us information about that ?

Regards,

Chris

What we did is to build an App with Forge API that is loaded from Autodesk servers, and also models rely on Autodesk servers. But we have to propose our customers to do that in a on-premise way.